# Can`t pass the two arguments $1 and $2 dynamic in a function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that takes 3 arguments

1 param: is a string,
2 param: a variable,
3 param: database cols values

The way i want to use this function is:

```
add_column('status', ('$1'<time() and '$2'>time()) ? "active" : "inactive", 'pack_activated_on,expire_on')
```

and every time it returns inactive.

If i use values instead of $1 and $2:

```
add_column('status', '1502197610'<time() and '1533675600'>time()) ? "active" : "inactive",'pack_activated_on,expire_on')
```

works (it return active).

The function return the corect values for the 2 params $1 and $2 (ex:)

```
add_column('status', '$1','pack_activated_on,expire_on')
```

i get the value of pack_activated_on = 1502197610

and the same for $2

```
add_column('status', '$2','pack_activated_on,expire_on')
```

get the value for expire_on = 1533675600

What i am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I don`t know why people give dislike, maybe the question is unclear? Just say and i will try to change the question!

Anyway....that function add_column is from this class [datatable class](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php) which using [datatable jQuery plugin server side](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in pure PHP. You are comparing literal `'$2'` with integer from `time()`. So PHP converts `'$2'` to integer 0, and compares with time() value - that is always false (`0 > 1533675600`).

You need to extract your `'$1'` to actual parameter instead of using reference to that (sorry, I do not know CodeIgniter for this part)

Comment: i am trying to cast the literall value to int but still not working. `add_column('status', ((int)'$1'<time() and (int)'$2'>time()) ? "active" : "inactive", 'pack_activated_on,expire_on')` The '$1' is the value of the first parameter and '$2' the value from the second parameter

Comment: @CălinBobeș `(int) '$2'` will be 0. Check before doing something further.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving your variables to the function as string literals. so your conditional has to avaluate string

just remove the single-quotes around your variables `$1` / `$2`

Comment: By PHP rules variables can't start with number.

Answer (score 0):

Contents inside of single quotes `'` are interpreted literally. What this means is you are literally comparing the string `$1` to `time()`.

There's no reason at all to wrap your variables in quotes in the context you have provided.

Also, as pointed out by Justinas, PHP variables cannot start with a number. So you should rename your variables to something meaningful.

So, solution is: just do e.g. `$variable_formally_known_as_1 < time()`.

Comment: By PHP rules variables can't start with number.

Comment: I've never actually bumped into that problem myself - got taught early on to give variables meanginful names. WIll update

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation for that function carefully and now works :)

```
  function status($var1, $var2){
     return ($var1<time() and $var2>time()) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
  }
```

and in the function:

```
add_column('status', '$1', 'status(pack_activated_on, expire_on)')
```